# How to make my react component rerender when I submit a form into firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Please I am trying to insert data into my firestore and also want the data that I stored to immediately appear on my screen after submitting. The problem I am currently having is that once I insert the data into firestore, I have to reload the component before seeing it on my screen. Here is my code below, what am I Doing wrongly.

```
function CreateGroup({ currentUser }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [group, setGroup] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;

    setName({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createGroup(currentUser, name.name);
  };


  let id = currentUser ? currentUser.id : "";
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      if (id) {
        firestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc(id)
          .collection("group")
          .get()
          .then(function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            //   console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
              setGroup({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
              });
            });
          });
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="exampleInputTitle">Group Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            aria-describedby="TitleHelp"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Add group{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <div key={group.id}>
          {group.name} {group.admin}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say, create a local state, say

```
 const [submited, setSubmited] = useState(true);
```

then on submit, change the state to true, and in your useEffect use "submitted" state also as a dependency along with id. OnHandleChange set "submitted" to false so we can submit again.

```
if (id) {}
```

becomes

```
if (id && submitted) {}
```

in the UseEffect.

```
function CreateGroup({ currentUser }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [group, setGroup] = useState([]);
const [submited, setSubmited] = useState(true);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;

    setName({
      [name]: value,
    });
setSubmited(false);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createGroup(currentUser, name.name);
setSubmited(true);
  };


  let id = currentUser ? currentUser.id : "";
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      if (id && submitted) {
        firestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc(id)
          .collection("group")
          .get()
          .then(function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            //   console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
              setGroup({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
              });
            });
          });
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [id, submitted]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="exampleInputTitle">Group Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            aria-describedby="TitleHelp"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Add group{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <div key={group.id}>
          {group.name} {group.admin}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can achieve this by checking first is firestore receive only:
-getting the data along after submission
-success response

the first scenario you will use .then to take the submitted data and set it to your local state.

the second scenario is to add another flag to your useeffect whenever you receive a successful response from firestore

```
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
/*
*if this method is async you can use .then
*/
   await createGroup(currentUser, name.name)
.then(res=>
//here you can set a state to trigger useeffect
)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      if (id) {
        firestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc(id)
          .collection("group")
          .get()
          .then(function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            //   console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
              setGroup({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
              });
            });
          });
      }
    };
//no need for this
    fetchData();
  }, [id,yourstateaftersubmit]);
```